# How to improve the speed of an n body simulation type project?

Tags: python, performance, optimization, simulation

I am making a particle simulation, where each particle has an attraction to each other particle, scaling with distance. In addition to this, I have added some other features such as eating food and using energy for the particles to move. I currently am simulating 100 particles, but the speed of the simulation is much slower than I would like at around 5 frames per second. I have optimised most of the calculations (for example, I no longer use trig - just square roots and basic operations), and am using JIT and vectorisation to speed up the maths and operate on all particles simultaneously. I am working in python, but the JIT should convert the intensive maths to a faster language.

To speed up the code I have made it so that the calculations are only made when particles are within a reasonable distance, I have also heard of splitting the simulation into chunks and simulating one chunk at a time, but this seems similar to what i am doing now and would involve a massive rewrite for mediocre performance gains compared to what I have.

Does anyone know of a way I can improve runtime? I would like to get it at 60 fps, so I am quite far out, but I think I have seen similar simulations which run much faster.

I have a lot of poorly written code, and I don't think that you can gain much from it,  but here are the relevant bits:

```
@guvectorize([(float64[:], float64[:],  int32, float64[:], float64[:])],'(m),(n),(),(p)->(n)', nopython=True)
def mathStuff(ipos, j, interact_range, matrix, vels2):
    vels2[2] = 0 
    vels2[3] = 0
    if (ipos[0] != j[0] and ipos[1] != j[1]):
        delta1 = (ipos[0]-j[0])
        delta2 = (ipos[1]-j[1])
        dist = (math.sqrt(delta1**2 + delta2**2))
        if in_range(dist, interact_range): # if j is in range 
            dx,sector = distance_calc(dist, interact_range) # get sector the particles are in
            if sector <= 4: # if close by, calculate remainder of the sector and repel based on that + inverse square law 
                #dy/dx = 3
                dx = (dx + sector +1)/5
                vel_mag = -(1/dx)**2
            elif sector > 4 and sector <= 16: #medium distance: scale from 0 attraction to attraction matrrix attraction
                dx = dx + sector-5
                grad = matrix[int(j[4])]/12
                vel_mag = grad*dx 
            elif sector >16 and sector <= 26: # large distance: scale from attraction matrix attraction down to 0 
                dx = dx + sector-16
                grad = matrix[int(j[4])]
                vel_mag = grad -(grad/10)*dx
            else: # too far - 0 velocity
                vel_mag= 0 
            vels = trig(delta2,delta1, vel_mag) # get what the velocity should be 
            vels2[0] = vels[0]
            vels2[1] = vels[1]
        else:
            vels2[0] = 0.0
            vels2[1] = 0.0
        if in_range(dist, interact_range/4):
            vels2[2] = int(j[4])+1
    else:
        vels2[0] = 0.0
        vels2[1] = 0.0
```

```
 for c1,i in enumerate(particles): # for each particle
        i.timestep(positions[c1][0],positions[c1][1]) # update position  
        positions[c1][2] = 0 
        positions[c1][3] = 0
         
        matrixes = [i.attraction_matrix[key] for key in i.attraction_matrix]
        expand_pos = np.concatenate((positions,np.asarray([types]).T), axis=1)
        v = np.asarray(mathStuff([(y) for y in positions[c1]],expand_pos, int(interact_range), matrixes))
```

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def in_range(dist, interact_range):
    if dist < math.sqrt(2*interact_range**2):
        return True
    else:
        return False 

# calculate the sector that a particle is in (based on distance split into 32 sectors)
@jit(nopython=True)
def distance_calc(other_dist, interact_range):
    other_dist = other_dist/(math.sqrt(2*interact_range**2)/32)
    dx = other_dist%1 
    sector = other_dist-dx 
    return dx,sector

# get velx and vely from velTotal and posx and posy 
@jit(nopython=True)
def trig(a,b, vel_mag):
    angle = a/b
    sign = np.sign(b)
    sqrt = math.sqrt(1+angle**2)
    self_vel0 = (-vel_mag/sqrt)*sign
    self_vel1 = self_vel0*angle
    return self_vel0,self_vel1
```

Comment: use some kind of multiprocessing on one of the loops. But to be honest, your task sounds like something for GPU

Comment: @dankal444 GPUs are not so great here. They might be slower than an optimized parallel CPU-based code. Indeed, there is many conditionals that can cause warp divergence, data-driven indexing that can cause non-contiguous memory accesses (ie. no coalescence). Not to mention double-precision computations are fast mainly on server-side GPUs, not client-side ones.

Comment: @Mercury Note that posting a full reproducible code help people to better locate bottlenecks an test some optimizations. This can typically improve the quality of the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is few improvements you can do:

- `if dist < math.sqrt(2*interact_range**2):` can be replaced to `if dist < math.sqrt(2) * interact_range:`. It will be significantly faster because square root are expensive and `math.sqrt(2)` can be computed at compile-time by Numba. In fact, the `in_range` function can be replaced by `return dist < math.sqrt(2) * interact_range`.
- `other_dist/(math.sqrt(2*interact_range**2)/32)` can be replaced by `other_dist * (32/math.sqrt(2)) / interact_range` for the same reasons.
- You can use the compilation flag `fastmath=True` if you are sure there is no special values (like NaN, Inf, or subnormals) produced by your code (even temporary). This can decrease the accuracy of the output (by breaking the floating-point associativity rules and more generally the IEEE-754 ones).
- If you do not use `fastmath`, then it is faster to use `a*(1/12)` than `a/12` since multiplications are faster than divisions. Also, `-(1/dx)**2` can be replaced by `-1/dx**2`.
- In the signature, `float64[:]` can be replaced by `float64[::1]` if the input array is contiguous. This help Numba do better vectorize loops when it is possible and simple (not much here).
- `matrix[int(j[4])]` can be replaced by `matrix[np.uint32(j[4])]` if you are sure the index value is positive. This helps Numba not to add some instructions to support *wraparound*.
- `int(j[4])+1` can be replaced by `np.ceil(j[4])` since `vels2[2]` hold a floating-point value (one need to be careful if the input is negative though so it is better to check the output match with your needs in this case).
- the `guvectorize` code can be parallelized (possibly with `parallel=True` or `target='parallel'`. However, this is certainly better to **use Numba in the caller code** (to avoid the overhead of calling a Numba function from Python which may be expensive in your case). Thus, this is certainly better to parallelize the outer-loop if possible. The later is only possible if there is **no dependency** (it is not clear to me if this is the case in the code). Indeed, parallelizing a loop with dependencies cause a *race condition*.
- If speed matters more than accuracy, then you can use single-precision instead of double-precision.

Comment: I implemented all of that except for the parallelization (guvectorize cannot be parallelized, and for the outer loop numba is unhappy when I use things such as lists of objects), but my performance increases were minor. It might be that parallelization is the most important part. Sidenote: I got it to work without no-python, but it just slowed the code down so i assume nopython is required.

Comment: I think a major bottleneck is the conditions since they prevent any hardware vectorization (ie. SIMD). If you could remove/reduce them or split the operation so to put conditional aside, it could significantly help. Note that data-dependent conditionals are a nightmare for the processor. For advanced optimizations, a full code would help as mentioned before. Profiling information could also help (though they are hard to retrieve). Regarding nopython, having it is better than not having it for performance.

Answer (score 1):

There are some great hints and advanced techniques in the other answer, but I'd recommend starting with some fundamentals....

It isn't totally clear because you haven't included all the necessary code, but it appears you are doing some nested looping in each frame where you are comparing each particle to many all others where you are enumerating `particles` and calling `mathSfuff` on a list of things that you are making.  I'd recommend letting `numpy` or `scipy` handle that type of thing and not create a bunch of data structures along the way.  The `cdist` function in `scipy` is about as fast as it gets to do N x N comparison.

The core thing, I think, is to put all of your particle x, y coords into a numpy vector and start thinking "how can I do this with linear algebra or numpy functions?"  Then all the magic is vectorized in `numpy` ops.

Below is an example that uses inverse force between 100 particles that runs for 1000 frames in ~500msec (with the plotting piece commented out) on my machine which is about ~2000fps.  There are still likely a few things that can be done here to speed this up, but it is broken down for clarity (and because I'm not a `numpy` ace.).  You could also tinker with the velocity vector or other things along the way if that is needed in your simulation.  If you run the below, the 100 particles on a 100x100 grid slowly coalesce to roughly the midpoint as seen in the output.  If you uncomment the distance squared, the system is quite unstable and probably needs some tweaks.  I also implemented a "minimum distance" of 1 to limit asymptotic behavior when particles come super close together.  The physics model might need some work, but the idea is to vectorize and then use LA.

Also, an aside, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73462481/solar-system-simulator-in-python-ursina/73463497#73463497) I posted a while back on `ursina` which is kind of a neat package that does this kind of stuff and has graphic output to boot.

##### Code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

num_pts = 100
F = 5  # some arbitrary force units
drag = 0.04
delta_t = .1

# make a 2-d vector of num_points random points on a 100x100 grid
pos = np.random.rand(num_pts, 2)*100
# print(pos)

# small for testing....
# pos = np.array([[0., 0.],
#               [0., 100.]])

# initial velocities = 0
vel = np.zeros(pos.shape)

y = []
t = []
# trial for 1000 frames
for frame in range(1000):

    # use cdist from scipy to get distances and make a distance matrix N x N
    dist = cdist(pos, pos, 'euclidean')
    dist = np.where(dist > 1, dist, 1)   # minimum distance of 1 for force computation

    # make a matrix of vectors between all pairs of points in pos
    # adding "new axis" allows element-wise subtraction and creation of N x N x 2 matrix
    deltas = pos[:, np.newaxis, :] - pos

    # normalize the delta vectors so that we create an N x N x 2 matrix of UNIT vectors between all points
    # we have to add a new axis to the dist matrix such that each x, y component is divided 
    dist_augment = dist[:, :, np.newaxis]
    deltas_norm = deltas/dist_augment

    # apply some inverse attractive force...  Make a N x N matrix of forces vectors (N x N x 2)
    forces = -deltas_norm * F / dist[:, :, np.newaxis]  # **2  <-- gets crazy quick!

    # sum the forces to get net force, per particle, add a little drag to slow the circus down...
    net_force = np.nansum(forces, axis=1) - drag*vel

    # state changes:
    vel += net_force * delta_t 
    pos += vel * delta_t

    # print("P", pos)
    y.append(pos[0][1])
    t.append(frame)

print('final position:')
print(pos)

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(t, y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This  seems like it will work very well. One thing I am slightly concerned about is if i can apply this to other functionality - if I add more interactions between particles where each particle interacts with each other particle, is there a way to implement this in a similar way? e.g particles breeding.